# The function dynamic_sidebar() is not working at all

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm developing a WordPress theme and I needed to add widgets to my header section so I used `register_sidebar()` in my functions.php:

```
function my_theme_add_widget_support()
{
    register_sidebar(array(
        'id' => 'header-2',
        'name' => 'the second hader'

    ));
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'my_theme_add_widget_support');
```

And then in the file header.php I wrote this code in the place where I wanted the widget to display but it doesn't display anything. I did a test to see if it's active and I found out that it's not active at all; even though I made sure that in the widgets area in my admin panel, the widget has something inside it:

```
<?php
if (is_active_sidebar('header-2')) {
    echo 'active';
    dynamic_sidebar('header-2')
} else {
    echo 'not active';
}
?>
```

This test always return not active.

PS: I'm using the old version of widgets editor.

Comment: did you try just `dynamic_sidebar('header-2)` to check if the sidebar is registered properly? Or try an earlier hook - like `after_setup_theme` instead of `widgets_init` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code, there might be a syntax issue or incorrect parameter configuration. Try updating your register_sidebar() function with the correct parameters and make sure to add a semicolon after **dynamic_sidebar('header-2')**. Here's the updated code:

```
<?php
if (is_active_sidebar('header-2')) {
    echo 'active';
    dynamic_sidebar('header-2');
} else {
    echo 'not active';
}
?>
```